# Aplicativo Mobile Android Web Rádio

Tags: android, streaming

Boa noite pessoal, alguém conhece algum tutorial ou já trabalhou como fazer um aplicativo web radio? Ele vai só transmitir o streaming de audio que já está online.

Comment: Apenas um pontapé inicial http://www.sitepoint.com/develop-music-streaming-android-app/
Depois eu transfiro como resposta @KaynanCoelho

Comment: Obrigado Wellington. Muito util.

Comment: Vou ver se consigo postar um exemplo hoje pra você @KaynanCoelho

Comment: Fico grato @WellingtonAvelino por sua ajuda, aguardando ansiosamente o seu exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Também já tinha se batido no começo, mas depois de estudos encontrei duas soluções, ambas eu gosto, já tentei as duas, mas a segunda parece ser mais estável pelo implemento ofertado na linha de código.  Você tem duas opções (além de outras, mas que funcionam geralmente apenas quando está apenas no app):

- Herdar o **StreamingMediaPlayer** (código:https://github.com/fcrohas/PoliSons/blob/master/src/fr/polisons/reader/StreamingMediaPlayer.java)
- Utilizando  **AAC Decoder**, livraria que há uns processos de conversão de áudio (https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/)

O segundo exemplo, já funciona no KitKat, o primeiro tem que adaptar.

Bom, vou mostrar um exemplo com o 1°, a partir dessa classe, que faz todo a transferência para rodar em segundo plano.

```
private StreamingMediaPlayer streamMedia;
//Para verificar se está tocando o não, quando aperta o botão:
private Boolean isPlaying;
//Para apertar o play (neste caso, a pausa utiliza do mesmo ID, que é este que é setado no momento de executá-lo).
private ImageButton playButton;

//Dentro do OnCreateView() além de indicar o layout fazemos o seguinte:
urlStreaming =  "http://linktransmissao.com/live.mp3";
//Lembrando que é aonde o fluxo é transmitindo, não a aba preparada para o navegador.
//Indicando quem éo playButton do XML:
playButton = ((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_play));
//Quando usuário clicar para tocar:  
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
//Quando for parar através do interrupt(), aparecer a imagem de play, para tocar novamente
        if (isPlaying)
        {
          audioStreamer.interrupt();
          playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
        }
//Quando for executar através do startStreamingAudio(), aparecer a imagem de pausa, caso deseje não ouvir mais.
        if (!isPlaying)
        {
          startStreamingAudio();
          playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
        }
     isPlaying=!isPlaying;
      }
    });
  }
  private void startStreamingAudio()
  {
    try
    {
//O áudio do streaming está funcionando, tentá-lo para-lo:
      if (this.audioStreamer != null)
        this.audioStreamer.interrupt();
//Chamando para um novo funcionamento pelo contexto, o mesmo playButton orientado na devida classe e a partir do url de valor String instanciado:
      this.audioStreamer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(this, playButton);
      this.audioStreamer.startStreaming(this.urlStreaming, 5208L, 216L);
      return;
    }
//Caso um eventual problema de execução, servindo para o sistema, não ao usuário: 
    catch (IOException localIOException)
    {
      while (true)
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error starting to stream audio.", localIOException);
    }
  }

//Por último para não ficar executando "infinitamente" o onDestroy() literalmente acaba com o áudio-o interrompendo para quando a aplicação está sendo encerrada, pois apenas fechá-la não faria parar de sair som.
protected void onDestroy()
  {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (this.audioStreamer != null)
      this.audioStreamer.interrupt();
  }
```

Em XML você pode montar usando essar variáveis que encaixem no contexto. Você pode adaptar como quiser, com outras funcionalidades, que podem ser editar em `StreamingMediaPlayer` também, como exemplo o `ProgressDialog` personalizado.

Uma opção para o controle de volume é o `SeekBar`:

```
private void definirVolumeSlider()
      {
  //Utilizando o sistema de áudio do Android, faz-se necessário importar o AudioManager, dois valores inteiro para o indicar o volume, indicando-o como máximo para 3 e o outro conforme pressionado, o progress referindo-se ao j, pois é o que é movimentado com o dedo para regular o volume como queira. 
        this.audioManager = ((AudioManager)getSystemService("audio"));
        int i = this.audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(3);
        int j = this.audioManager.getStreamVolume(3);
        setVolumeControlStream(3);
        SeekBar localSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        localSeekBar.setMax(i);
        localSeekBar.setProgress(j);
  //Clicando então para selecionar, inicialmente no máximo:         
        localSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
          public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar paramAnonymousSeekBar, int paramAnonymousInt, boolean paramAnonymousBoolean)
          {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(3, paramAnonymousInt, 0);
          }
 //Este dois últimos seria mais para música propriamente dito, para as trilhas:
          public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramAnonymousSeekBar)
          {
          }

          public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramAnonymousSeekBar)
          {
          }
        });
      }
```

Para colocara notificação, eu fiz o seguinte:

```
 private void notification()
  {
    NotificationManager localNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService("notification");
    PendingIntent localPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,  Nomedaclasseemquestao.class), 0);
    localNotificationManager.notify(1, new Notification.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(2130837515).setContentTitle("Seu título aqui. Ex: nome da rádio").setContentText("Texto. Ex:slogan da rádio").setOngoing(true).setContentIntent(localPendingIntent).build());
  }
```

Para o `isPlaying`

```
//Quando está sem tocar, sem aparecer notificação     
      ((NotificationManager)RadioStation.this.getSystemService("notification")).cancel(1);
```

Para o `!isPlaying`

```
//Está tocando, a notificação fica visível      
notification();
```

Pelo problema de tocar no KitKat é no protocolo: basta fazer assim para solucionar o encoder de transmissão no OnCreateView():

```
String str = "http";
//Corrigindo o bug do ICY (Icecast, tipo de transmissão depois do API 18)
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
    {
        setupIcyURLStreamHandler();
        str2 = "icy";
    }
urlStreaming = (str2 + "://linktransmissao.com/live.mp3");


 //Construindo então o método citado:
    private void setupIcyURLStreamHandler()
    {
        try
        {
            URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new URLStreamHandlerFactory() {
                public URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler(String paramAnonymousString) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "Asking for stream handler for protocol: '" + paramAnonymousString + "'");
                    if ("icy".equals(paramAnonymousString)) ;
                    for (IcyURLStreamHandler localIcyURLStreamHandler = new IcyURLStreamHandler(); ; localIcyURLStreamHandler = null)
                        return localIcyURLStreamHandler;
                }
            });
            return;
        }
        catch (Throwable localThrowable)
        {
            while (true)
                Log.w("LOG", "Cannot set the ICY URLStreamHandler - maybe already set ? - " + localThrowable);
        }
    }
```

Neste caso, aproveita a classe `IcyURLStreamHandler` do mesmo AAC Decoder, colocando o pacote `com.spoledge.aacdecoder` em `libs`.

Para usar o `AAC Decoder` pode se baser neste exemplo próprio de quem disponibilizou:https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/source/browse/trunk/player/src/com/spoledge/aacplay/AACPlayerActivity.java*.

* Spolecne, 2011. spoledge.com